# Handling Dates while copying from Excel to SQL server database table in Talend

Tags: sql, excel, date, talend, smalldatetime

I am copying data from an Excel workbook to the SQL server database table.
One of the column in my Excel sheet has Dates, which I am generating using Rand function.

If I keep data types of my columns as string in both my Excel input and SQL output.
I get an error which says
"Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type."

If I keep my datatypes as Date it gives as error which says 
"The cell format is not Date in ....(cell address)"

In my table's definition in SQL server. It has data type as 'smalldatetime'.

To solve this problem I am using tConvertType.
But I am getting an error which says:
"The cell format is not Date in ....(cell address)"

I have attached my job's screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use TalendDate.parseDate method for conversion...
this can be used in expression in tMap..so your flow with reading date from excel as String and converting it to date using TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","")

input -> tmap -> tmssqloutput components.

Comment: I have tried it but it still gives an error.
Please see my screenshots here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920933/unparseable-date-error-talend/23927374#23927374

Comment: i have added more validation to that post also. please check

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the type in your Talend job.

Read the date in as a string and then use a tConvertType component to convert the type from string to a date type with a specific date format. You should then be able to send this to the database as a `smalldatetime` data type

Comment: Hey, my job has excel input -> tmap -> tmssqloutput components.
where and how do I use tConvertType component?

Comment: Will my new job flow be like:
Excel Input -> tConvertType -> tMap -> tMSSqlOutput ?

Comment: I have tried but it gives me an error which says
"java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Nov 30 00:00:00 EST 2001"

Comment: Can you edit you question to provide an example of the dates coming in and also a screenshot of your job as it is now? Also show the configuration of your tConvertType if possible (I'm assuming this is what's throwing the error here?)

Comment: I have edited the question with the screenshot.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TCmUs8_9uM

I have kept setting as shown in this video.
Note: even though I have selected Repository from the drop down for schema it gets changed to built-in.

Comment: The error message you're seeing there seems to imply that you're still reading in column 18 as a date instead of a string

Comment: Yes, I corrected them still I have an error which says:
"java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 17 00:00:00 EDT 1973"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920933/unparseable-date-error-talend

Here I have posted the rephrased question. Please have a look.