# Unparseable Date error - Talend

Tags: date, talend, parseexception

I am trying to copy data from Excel to a SQL table.

I have dates generated in Excel file using RAND function. I am taking them as strings in an input and trying to convert them in date data type using tConvertType.

I have setted its datatype as 'string' in initial input and as 'date' in tConvertType's output and in tMSSqlOutput.

My job has work flow Excel input -> tConvertType -> tMap -> tMSSqlOutput.
While running the job I am getting an error which says : 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue Jul 17 00:00:00 EDT 1973"

I am not sure where the problem lies.
If anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Here's the screenshot of my job.
[image]

Comment: As asked in previous questions, can you show how the tconverttype is configured and the schema for it?

Comment: Instead of convert type you can use tMap to convert dates using TalendDate routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am able to parse your given sample date please use below function in tMap for your date filed.

`System.out.println(TalendDate.parseDateLocale("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 'Tue Jul 17 00:00:00 EDT 1973', "EN"));`

function is `yourDateColumn!=null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(yourDateColumn)? TalendDate.parseDateLocale("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", yourDateColumn, "EN") :null`

Answer (score 0):

@UmeshR: your code is working fine, but you have to handle the timezone thing as well. e.g. I am from India and when i converted the time from EDT talend converted it to my local timezone. see the screen-shot[image].